# Electric Field Divergence

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, vector-fields

I found a statement written in Introduction to Electrodynamics which mentions that if "Electric field lines terminate somewhere midway in the air, then divergence of Electric field will not be 0". But it is the curl which is zero. Is this a printing error or is there sone other meaning of this statement?

Comment: In regions where there are no electric charges the divergence is zero. If the electric field lines "end" somewhere you've got a sink for the electric field and so the divergence will be non-zero.

Comment: The point of this statement is to give you some intuition for what the divergence means. It is not meant as to describe Maxwell's equations.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, divergence is the amount of flux that would pass per unit volume at a point. If the divergence is zero then that implies that what goes into the point is what comes out if you were to look in terms of field lines. Thus in a way if field lines were terminating at a point then that either means they are emanating from a point or closing in at the point which is often loosely said source and sink.

Now it is a known fact that field lines terminate only when there is some charge at that point. By Maxwell's law this implies that divergence is not zero.

Comment: Yes I actually assumed it for the general case and didn't notice this case properly